# Java литература

Tags: java

Посоветуйте толколвую книгу по изучению java с нуля, много литературы в интернете, но какая из них будет более полезнее? Желательно чтобы читалось полегче. Интересует от самых базовые понятий до swing'a

И еще Java vs JavaFX что проще изучается? Стабильнее работает ...

Answer (score 2):

- Брюс Эккель. Философия Java
- Яков Файн. Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, дедушек и бабушек
- Джошуа Блох. Эффективное программирование
- Герберт Шилдт. Java 8. Руководство для начинающих
- Кен Арнольд, Джеймс Гослинг. Язык программирования Java
- Патрик Нимейер и Дэниэл Леук. Программирование на Java
- Алексей Васильев. Java. Объектно-ориентированное программирование

Comment: Начинать наверное лучше с  Head First Java( Кэти Сиерра, Берт Бейтс ). А потом безусловно Брюс Эккель(недавно вышлел полный перевод его книги) хотя некоторые предпочитают Хорстманна.